# Bookstrap css not working with codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have created a controller in codeigniter.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Main extends CI_Controller{

    public function login(){

        $this->load->view('view_login');
    }
}
```

and Below is my view.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Voyager</title>
        <link href="../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="../../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="panel panel-heading">
                    This is Heading
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </td>    
        </tr>

    </table>    

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>
        <script src="../../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

With this Code, Page is rendered but CSS is not applied.

Am I missing something?

Another question which I have is Why do we need helper, I have added code to autoload helper. Why do we need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You have to add full path to get CSS styles

CodeIgniter is a MVC structure and file actually call from controller so we can't get actual path so we have to add Full Url of any file so we can not get any type of issue or error.

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

And also change your config/config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yoursitefolder'; // you can set your working url
```

Comment: for script tag too?

Comment: <script src>,<img src> but only file upload then we use path otherwise all things we have to convert into full url

Comment: yup. did that. still same issue

Comment: CSS is not applied to controls and texts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141618/discussion-between-imbs-and-dkr).

Comment: Changing config file for baseurl worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: End base url with `/ `on config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yoursitefolder/'`

Comment: it does not matter @wolfgang1983 check in your project

Comment: check this in codeigniter docs in this codeigniter also end baseurl without / https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_303.html

Answer (score 0):

Is files really 2 folders up before assets ?

folder1/folder2/assets ???

Comment: Yup. I have dragged those files. Asset diectory is in root directory

Comment: I think there shouldnt be any other problem

Comment: try to replace just for test css and js links with real links and see what happens

Comment: what do you mean by real links? these are real links

Answer (score 0):

Go to your config.php and set base_url:

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

and then in your view:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and same in scripts

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```